# What is the fastest way to keep a subversion repository in sync for migrating to a new environment?

Tags: linux, svn, synchronization

I'm attempting to migrate large subversion repositories from a system with subversion 1.6 to one with subversion 1.7.  When I make the final sync, I can take downtime and simply use rsync, but I didn't choose this because I wanted the new repositories to be created/upgraded with version 1.7.

So I chose to use svnsync because it can pick up where it left off and because the repositories are not mounted on the same device.  The only problem is for large repositories `svnsync copy-revprops` takes FOREVER, as it goes through every revision over again.

So my question is can I do one of:

- Reduce the time it takes to do svnsync copy-revprops
- Skip copy-revprops entirely
- Use a faster method of incrementally syncing repositories from one version of subversion to another.

?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnsync.c.copy-revprops.html:

> Because Subversion revision properties can be changed at any time,
>   it's possible that the properties for some revision might be changed
>   after that revision has already been synchronized to another
>   repository. Because the svnsync synchronize command operates only on
>   the range of revisions that have not yet been synchronized, it won't
>   notice a revision property change outside that range. Left as is, this
>   causes a deviation in the values of that revision's properties between
>   the source and mirror repositories. svnsync copy-revprops is the
>   answer to this problem. Use it to resynchronize the revision
>   properties for a particular revision or range of revisions.

This means that you can choose to skip copy-revprops if the revision properties have not been changing.  Even if you're not sure, there is no point in doing copy-revprops multiple times--once at the very end of all sync's will suffice.